# Disable Fields by clicking links

Tags: jquery

I'd like to disable specific fields from the form each time I click on a link

Here are the links:

```
<ul id="links">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="active" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"> Form Type 1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a id="drop1" href="#dropdown1">Form #1</a>
      <a id="drop2" href="#dropdown2">Form #2</a>
      <a id="drop3" href="#dropdown3">Form #3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"> Form Type 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a id="drop4" href="#dropdown4">Form #4</a>
      <a id="drop5" href="#dropdown5">Form #5</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="add.php" class="form" id="megaform">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" maxlength="50">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Location</label>
      <input type="text" id="Location" name="Location" maxlength="75">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Product</label>
      <input type="text" id="Product" name="Product" maxlength="100">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Age</label>
      <input type="text" id="Age" name="Age" maxlength="2">
    </div>
```

So for example by default it will have `Form #1` active which will have Product & Age disabled, when I click the link `Form #2` will enable Product & Age and disable Location etc.

Edit:
I've been trying to make it work with the following code but I fail:

```
<script>
  $("#drop2").click(function(){
      $("#Location").prop("disabled", true\false);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Where's your current JS logic? Remember that we're here to help you debug code that ***you*** have written, not to write code for you

Comment: Also why form 3 comes in between 1 and 2 in your Form HTML? As you said:- `So for example by default it will have Form #1 active which will have Product & Age disabled, when I click the link Form #2 will enable Product & Age and disable Location etc.`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've tried a few different approaches but nothing worked so I haven't included any of them. The last one I've added now works with a button but not with a link like the ones above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on("click", function(){
       var formId  = $(this).attr('id');
       if(formId == 'drop1'){ //whatever id you want
        $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
         var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
            
            if( inputId == 'Product' || inputId == 'Age' ){ 
              $(this).prop('disabled',true);
            }else{
                $(this).prop('disabled',false);
            }
        })
       }else if(formId == 'drop2'){ //whatever id you want
          $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
           var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
              if( inputId == 'Location'){ 
                      $(this).prop('disabled',true);
              }else{
                     $(this).prop('disabled',false);
              }
         })
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="links">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="active" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"> Form Type 1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a id="drop1" href="#dropdown1">Form #1</a>
      <a id="drop2" href="#dropdown2">Form #2</a>
      <a id="drop3" href="#dropdown6">Form #3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"> Form Type 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a id="drop4" href="#dropdown10">Form #4</a>
      <a id="drop5" href="#dropdown11">Form #5</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<form method="post" action="add.php" class="form" id="megaform">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" maxlength="50">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Location</label>
      <input type="text" id="Location" name="Location" maxlength="75">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Product</label>
      <input type="text" id="Product" name="Product" maxlength="100">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Age</label>
      <input type="text" id="Age" name="Age" maxlength="2">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: when you click on link you need to  .each on all input fields bcz you have to first enable all input field after that disable fields accordingly.